# Python os.walk and opening apps/files

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to make a script that crawls through the Applications directory and open up a given file. So here is my code

```
import os, subprocess

os.chdir('/Applications')
root = '.'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    #print path
    for f in files:
        if f == 'Atom':
            subprocess.call([f])
            break
```

So I have three questions.
At first I used Atom as the example to execute the script. It opens up fine, but even after opening the app the loop doesn't break and keeps crawling.

Second, the Atom app doesn't open up as it would normally do. It opens up in the directory of the applications folder, which looks something like this.
[image]

While it should merely look like this,
[image]

And the very important problem is that it didn't work for any other applications which I couldn't understand. Here is the error output when I tried to open AppStore.

```
./App Store.app
./App Store.app/Contents
./App Store.app/Contents/_CodeSignature
./App Store.app/Contents/MacOS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "control_files.py", line 32, in <module>
    subprocess.call([f])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: You have two for-loops. Break will only break out of the inner loop.

Atom probably opens in the Applications directory because you use os.chdir to go there.  You can start the walk in that folder withouth using chdir first. `os.walk('/Applications')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers are spot-on about `break` only exiting the innermost loop.

Another way to escape the loop, and probably neater, would be to hide away this functionality in a function and `return` from it. Something along the lines of:

```
def open_program(root, filename):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        if filename in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
            subprocess.call([full_path])
            return
```

IMO using `filename in files` makes the code cleaner, and does pretty much the same work.